Size of the ggplot2 grid
I'm trying to plot my results for the tree crowns I detected in a part of the Canadian boreal forest. And I would like to know how to know how much represents a cell of the grid that we see appearing in font of my plot. Can I change the value of the cells so that they represent 1ha, 1/2ha, 1/10ha, etc?

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = crowns4_crop, aes(fill = convhull_area)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "Crown area (m²)") + 
  geom_sf(data = ttops4_crop, color = "red", pch = 3, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE)  + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + 
  labs(title = "Crown & Tree")

I tried playing with the different parameters of ggplot2 (but I'm not an expert with this package), I also looked on the internet.

The size of the grid will be visible if you don't turn off the axis text in theme, they are probably in terms of degrees latitude and longitude. I don't know how to express that in terms of hectares though.

To get 1 hectare squares in your grid, set your breaks to every 100 m (example). If your coordinates aren't already in meters, convert them UTM (example).
